# rails 5: while submitting forms I do not get any errors but my data is not stored in the database. Why?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is my routes.rb

```
  root 'categories#index'
  resources :listings
resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories
end
```

here is my new.html.erb for Listings/ Posts

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="contact-area">
    <%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
      <%= f.label :city %>
      <%= f.text_field :city %>
      <%= f.label :state %>
      <%= f.text_field :state %>
      <%= f.label :zipcode %>
      <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: "zip-width", maxlength: "5" %>
      <%= f.submit class:"create-button" %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my listing.rb file::

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subcategory
  def listing
        params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :zipcode)
    end
end
```

Here is my Controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    @listing.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :zipcode)
  end
```

I am having the same issue using rails 5. Please let me know if you could solved this.

I am able to create a form but while submitting the form I have an issue, my data are not saved in my database and every time I put query on irb: as  Listing.first, the answer is nil. I did searched online for the issue, they said that check your closing tags on forms, check your route.rb etc. I have verified everything and yet my issue is not resolved.

Please reply me, i am very beginner at Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Do you have any validation in your `Listing` model? How does the log for the requests look like?

Comment: You really should be checking if `@listing.save` succeeds or not. Ignoring error checking is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Rails 5 onwards an association specified using `belongs_to` is [required by default](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233). This means a `Listing` is not valid and won't save if it doesn't have a subcategory.

You can make it optional by changing your model to have:

```
belongs_to :subcategory, required: false
```

---

`save` will return `true` if your model passes validation and is saved successfully and `false` if not. In general, your `create` and `update` actions should have a structure that handles this:

```
if @listing.save
  redirect_to root_path
else
  # redisplay the form if validation failed
  render action: 'new'
end
```

Another tip is that you can use `save!` which will raise an exception (and so display an error message) if your model fails validation. Changing `@listing.save` to `@listing.save!` is a quick way to get a helpful error message telling you why the model isn't being stored.

Answer (score 0):

> *I do not get any errors*

[`@listing.save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) will silently return false if it fails.

You can check for failure, or you can use [`@listing.save!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) which will throw an [ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html) exception if the save fails. In either case you can then [use `@listing.errors` or `exception.record.errors`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) to find out what went wrong.